# SSRS - How to prevent from SSRS generate empty reports to subscription module

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have SSRS report invoice.rdl which run every 30 minutes and generate new output CSV file in folder `C:\Output`.

In SQL I have a stored procedure `spInvoice` which generates this report.

Sometimes output from the stored procedure is empty and CSV file has only headers.

**Question**: how to prevent creating a `.CSV` file if all lines are empty except headers?

Comment: You would normally use a data-driven subscription to control this. These are only available in the Enterprise version of SQL Server. If you only have SQL Server Standard edition then you could add a job to run the subscription only if the SP returns data. The job would run the SP, check the row count and then execute the report or subscription if the rowcount was not zero. There are plenty of similar questions on here about how to emulate data-driven subs if you do not have Enterprise.

Comment: You say you have an SP that generates the report. Why not add a check in SP to see if there are any records and trigger the report from the SP? `EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType = 'TimedSubscription', @EventData = 'abc1234567-abcd-1234-1234-0123456789'`